# What is the difference between Google Container Engine and Container-Optimized Compute Engine?

Tags: containers, google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a little bit of an idea about their differences, but it would be great to have expert opinions.

- [Container-Optimized Google Compute Engine Images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms)
- [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Container Engine is a [kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/) backed cluster manager. It makes managing simple or complex docker based applications easy. Easy in the form of configuration, updating and scaling.

The container optimized compute engine images allows you to run docker containers on a single node. Note, you can create your own containerized cluster with this image if you wish, but if you're going down this path you should really reconsider container engine.

It's worth noting that the container optimized image also has aspects of kubernete's in the form of a kubelet.